# DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause

Tags: android, kotlin

The app is crashed when opening the camera/image gallery, but not sure what the problem is.

```
D/ViewRootImpl@c86a903[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
D/ViewRootImpl@c86a903[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={valid=false 0} changed=false
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 12216)
E/Parcel: Invalid object type 0x00660037
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=HIGHEST, name=FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_REPORT for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Scheduling upload for context TransportContext(cct, HIGHEST, MSRodHRwczovL2NyYXNobHl0aWNzcmVwb3J0cy1wYS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MS9maXJlbG9nL2xlZ2FjeS9iYXRjaGxvZ1xBSXphU3lCcnBTWVQ0RkZMMDlyZUhKaTZIOUZZZGVpU25VVE92Mk0=) with jobId=-407685770 in 1000ms(Backend next call timestamp 1638127305049). Attempt 1
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:64975', transport: 'socket'
```